# Displaying detailed error messages other than that what is defined in Fluent Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` and the latest version of `Fluent Validation`. I am using Fluent Validation over data annotations.

I am looking at adding a validation error summary to my view where data is to be entered.  I currently just use the `ValidationMessageFor` with each input field.  Sometimes I need to do other validation (like against a service) after the form validation is true, and then have these messages displayed on the view if the validation failed.  And because this validation is not related to any input field I want to have this error displayed in a validation error summary.

Lets take for example my employee number field, it is required and it cannot be longer than 10 characters.  I have the following validator class using Fluent Validation:

```
public class CreateEmployeeViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateEmployeeViewModel>
{
     public CreateEmployeeViewModelValidator()
     {
          RuleFor(x => x.EmployeeNumber)
               .NotEmpty()
               .WithMessage("Required")
               .Length(1, 10)
               .WithMessage("Must not be greater than 10 characters");
     }
}
```

My HTML markup:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmployeeNumber)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmployeeNumber)
```

This part works fine.  If the textbox is empty then it displays the "Required" error message next to the textbox, and if it is more than 10 characters then it displays the "Must not be greater than 10 characters" error message.

Now I want to add my validation error summary to the view.  I added the following:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Errors have occurred while. Fix the errors before saving.")
```

I would like it to display some decent error message relating to the control above.  Although it displays "Required" next to the employee number if it is empty, I would like it to display something like "Employee number is required" in the validation error summary.  Currently it just displays the text "Errors have occurred while. Fix the errors before saving.".

And when I need to do other validation after form validation is true, like check if the employee is a valid employee, then I also want this error message to be displayed. If I have this in my controller's action method:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "My test error message");
```

I would like to have "My test error message" to be displayed in the validation error summary.

How would something like this be possible?

Comment: That should already be working. So is the additional error message not showing in the summary?

Comment: The error message from the controller it displays, but I'm trying to get the detailed error message into the validation summary if the form validation is false.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should set it up

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

Say you don't validate on the client-side or validation there fails, when your form is submitted you have those errors available in your controller. You can then add more errors just as you are adding it now:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "My test error message");
```

When the view is rendered back to your client it will contain the error message from your model's properties plus the custom messages.

**UPDATE:**

Brendan mentioned that he wants to show a short message besides each of the erring control as well as to provide a longer version of the error message for the same erring control, and show that longer version of the error message in the ValidationSummary. It can be done with a bit of a hack.

Suppose the model has a property called `EmployeeNumber` as is shown in the question. The form is submitted back and it is validated on the server side using the custom validator setup by Brendan. All is good. Now we can use reflection and inspect the model's properties and find if an error exist in the modelstate dictionary, use the property name and look it up in some error collection object (could be a resource file or a database, all the same approach).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AcceptEmployee(EmployeeModel model)
{
    // customErrors here is a dictionary 
    // that contains information for the custom message        
    // i.e. Key="EmployeeNumber", Message="Employee number is required"
    // like I've mentioned this can be a query from the database
    // or a get from a resource file
    // for the sake of this example, I used a dictionary
    foreach (var property in model.GetType().GetProperties())
    {        
        if (ModelState[property.Name] !=null 
            && ModelState[property.Name].Errors.Any())
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", customErrors[property.Name]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now make sure you exclude property errors from the summary by doing:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

So now you can enjoy having a short error besides an erring control and a (very) long error message in a summary.

Comment: Doing it this way will display "Required" in the summary. "Required" means nothing, I want a descriptive error message like "Employee number is required" in the summary. Next to the control "Required" is ok.

Comment: Is modifying your validator an option? Like this: `.WithMessage("Employee number is required")`? If it is then that will do it. If not then I'm sorry my answer is not sufficient.

Comment: Yes this will do it, but I don't want such a long message next my control. Required is fine. There has to be a way to do this :)

Comment: Your answer is ok. It's not the end of the world if it can't be done.

Comment: Ah I think I understand more what you want to do. It can be done but it requires a bit of a hack. What you can do is read the modelstatedictionary then find if a field is with an error. Then supply a longer version of that error adding it as a custom error. Then use the validationsummary to exclude property errors (`@html.validationsummary(true)`).

Comment: @BrendanVogt see my updated answer, I just gave an example of how to hack it :)

Answer (score 0):

@Html.ValidationSummary(true) -->Correct

1. Will not display default error messages all together.
2. You will be able to display custom messages by just writing the below statement
   `ModelState.AddModelError("", "This account is not registered in our system.");`
3. All the annotation messages defined in the class will be displayed right next to the controls neatly.